# Why won't newly installed light kit work at same time as ceiling fan is on?

Tags: ceiling, ceiling-fan, light

I installed LED light kit to ceiling fan that had an old Hunter 3 speed control wall switch. The romex is only 14-2 going from ceiling to wall switch so I know I can't control both the fan and light kit from the wall unless I change to 14-3. The fan works with wall switch or pull chain. The light works with pull chain but I can't get both to work at same time. If light is on and I put fan on the light goes off. What is causing this? Why won't both fan and light work together?

Comment: Can you provide some pictures of the light kit diagram and fan wiring?. Have you checked to see if the lights come on at all three fan speeds?

Comment: I don't have a picture and threw the box away.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you connected the light neutral to the motor (switched hot) line.

So, fan motor off, light gets power, power returns through the motor to neutral, isn't enough power being an LED light kit to turn the fan.

Fan motor on, light has power, motor has power, no voltage difference across the light, light does not light. Fan runs happily.